# Uploading larger images (5-10mb) serverside, is Base64 a good option?

Tags: rest, encoding, base64

Im just curious, how are people handing larger image sizes on upload these days. I am working with a project that currently uses base64 encoding on user images being uploaded, I am going to work on another functionality which will allow larger images uploaded and i am wondering if i should re-use this logic.
Base64 strings can be quite heavy and large when hitting the server, is there any downsides to this approach when we get to the > 5MB image file size threshold ? and if so how are you handing this logic.

As there is not code to my question i thought i would leave this here for reference, its quite old but a decent read on the topic

https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/